# GAE Python NDB query fetch response time >55 seconds when only ~50 entities are present

Tags: sql, google-app-engine, python-2.7, app-engine-ndb

We have a travel search website. To search for a bus, we execute a query on the bus operator entities. We use GAE Python NDB. The query fetch response time >55 seconds(on deployed version and not development server) when only ~50 entities are present.

Presently my query contains five items. If I increase to more than five, the response slows further considerably. Please suggest ways to bring down the query time to ~1 or 2 seconds or as less as possible.
Please find the relevant details below(sorry i tried to minimize the below content to some extent):

Query code:

```
start_time = datetime.datetime.now() 
qry_1 = X.query(ndb.AND(X.active_status=="active", X.property_3==input_3, X.property_4==input_4, X.property_5==input_5, X.property_6.IN(input_6_list), X.property_20.IN(input_20_list))) 
record_list = qry_1.fetch() 
query_end_time = datetime.datetime.now() 
query_execution_time = query_end_time - start_time 
logging.info ("query_execution_time=["+str(query_execution_time)+"] ") 

# input_6_list contains ~5 string items 
# input_20_list contains ~5 string items
```

Output in Logs:

```
query_execution_time=[0:00:55.925250]
```

Entity Model:

```
class X(ndb.Model): 
    active_status = ndb.StringProperty() 
    name = ndb.StringProperty() 
    property_1 = ndb.StringProperty() 
    property_2 = ndb.TextProperty() 
    property_3 = ndb.StringProperty() 
    property_4 = ndb.StringProperty() 
    property_5 = ndb.StringProperty() 
    property_6 = ndb.StringProperty() 
    property_7 = ndb.StringProperty() 
    property_8 = ndb.StringProperty() 
    property_9 = ndb.StringProperty(repeated=True) 
    property_10 = ndb.StringProperty(repeated=True) 
    property_11 = ndb.StringProperty() 
    property_12 = ndb.StructuredProperty(P) 
    property_13 = ndb.StructuredProperty(Q) 
    property_14 = ndb.StringProperty() 
    property_15 = ndb.StructuredProperty(R, repeated=True) 
    property_16 = ndb.StructuredProperty(S, repeated=True) 
    property_17 = ndb.StringProperty() 
    property_18 = ndb.StringProperty(repeated=True) 
    property_19 = ndb.StringProperty() 
    property_20 = ndb.StringProperty(repeated=True) 
    property_21 = ndb.StringProperty(repeated=True) 
    property_22 = ndb.StructuredProperty(T, repeated=True) 
    property_23 = ndb.IntegerProperty(default=6) 
    property_24 = ndb.IntegerProperty(default=6) 
    property_25 = ndb.IntegerProperty(default=6) 
    property_26 = ndb.IntegerProperty(default=6) 
    property_27 = ndb.IntegerProperty(default=6) 
    property_28 = ndb.IntegerProperty(default=0) 
    property_29 = ndb.IntegerProperty() 
    date_added = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True) #creation date 
    date_modified = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True) #update date 
    property_30 = ndb.TextProperty() 
    property_31 = ndb.BlobKeyProperty() 
    property_32 = ndb.BlobKeyProperty() 
    property_33 = ndb.BlobKeyProperty() 
    property_34 = ndb.BlobKeyProperty() 
    property_35 = ndb.BlobKeyProperty() 
    property_36 = ndb.BlobKeyProperty() 
    property_37 = ndb.BlobKeyProperty() 
    property_38 = ndb.StringProperty() 
    property_39 = ndb.BlobKeyProperty() 
    property_40 = ndb.StringProperty(default="not_allowed")
```

While debugging this issue, I ran Appstats and had [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22329224/gae-appstats-rpc-timeline-graph-shows-long-gaps) which I asked on SO

Comment: The AND and the IN are probably expensive because of searching multiple indexes and looping internally.  If you could re-structure your entities somehow to avoid those in your queries, response times should reduce dramatically.

Comment: Yeah, that query is going to be VERY expensive.  Try running that code  with just one operator/comparison and compare time (e.g. just use status == 'active').  I have projects with more properties, and retrieving hundreds of entities in 00's of milliseconds.

Comment: Also, would it improve "query" response time if I give "indexed" as "false" for certain properties which I am not going to use in the "query"..

Comment: @Martin Thanks Martin for your reply.. I cannot convert the related properties from array to individual elements as the number of items they contain would vary and could increase.. And so it would be difficult to remove the IN.. I can try removing IN and AND from query and fetch a bigger result set.. And then iterate through the results myself and put "if" statements to select the result entities matching the conditions.. But, I thought the Query would be more efficient and less time taking than my implementation..

Comment: @Tim Thanks Tim for your reply.. Looking at your query response number(~0ms), I felt a new leash of life :) Could you pl elaborate more or put as an answer.. I think that could be the answer to my question.. Do you mean that I should query based on only one filter condition(say, "active_status") and then iterate through the obtained result entities and use "if" statements to select the ones that match my other filter criteria.. But I fear if I have more entities, would I run out of memory since I would be getting a bigger entity result list after the "query""fetch"..

Comment: @gsinha I would suggest you try a few different queries and measure the performance. You may find you get reasonable performance with 2 conditions, - I would see how many conditions you can use before performance drops off too much.  Also you might find some other precomputed property might allow you to short circuit the complex query but we don't have anough info to suggest things.  As an aside additional indexes will only affect write performance.

Comment: @TimHoffman I tried `qry_1 = X.query(X.property_5==input_5 )` but still the response time ~45 seconds.. Any suggestions

Comment: Hmm, that runs completely counter to my experience.  I had a project a few years back that had over 80 properties and that never performed remotely as bad, and that was querying for 100's of records. You are testing against live appengine.  What sort of value is stored in property_5?  I think you probably need to break this down further.  See what performance you get with much smaller entities.  Have you used appstats to profile what sort of roundtrips you are seeing.

Comment: @TimHoffman Thanks.. I added Appstats but was not able to understand the gaps in the Timeline graph between RPC calls.. I have asked a question for the same http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22329224/gae-appstats-rpc-timeline-graph-shows-long-gaps

Answer (score 2):

Filtering on additional properties is not usually expensive.  But using 'IN' is.  2 IN filters with lists of 5 items each requires 25x concurrent seeks on the backend.

Could you post the index.yaml file from your code directory?  If this file does not exist, the query would require multiple JOINs, which would explain the slowness.  Run the same query against the dev_appserver and it will generate the file automatically.

More here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/indexconfig

By the way, using 'indexed=False' on the properties you don't intend to search on will reduce the cost puts considerably.

Comment: Any idea if I use query cursor with fetch of 50 entities only out of a total of 10000 query matched result entities, would the query be as slow as the time required to fetch all the results(10000) or only as slow as for 50 entities..

Comment: Data is only fetched as needed, so it will be faster.  But you'll still want an index for the query, otherwise the query requires an operation similar to a JOIN for each field in the filters, which will be slow.