# Read and Write Operations involved with ComputedProperty in GAE NDB

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I use GAE NDB Python 2.7
My two Models code:

```
class A(ndb.Model): 
    def X(self, value): 
        :: # some statements to return a value 
        return range 
    def Y(self, value): 
        :: # some statements to return a value 
        return range 
    def Z(self, value): 
        :: # some statements to return a value 
        return range 

    property_1 = ndb.IntegerProperty(default=0, indexed=False) 
    property_2 = ndb.IntegerProperty(default=0, indexed=False) 
    property_3 = ndb.IntegerProperty(default=0, indexed=False) 
    property_4 = ndb.IntegerProperty(indexed=False) 
    # Computed values 
    computed_property_1 = ndb.ComputedProperty(lambda e: e.X(e.property_1)) 
    computed_property_2 = ndb.ComputedProperty(lambda e: e.Y(e.property_2)) 
    computed_property_3 = ndb.ComputedProperty(lambda e: e.Z(e.property_3)) 
    date_added = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True, indexed=False) 
    date_modified = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True, indexed=False) 

class B(ndb.Model): 
    property_5 = ndb.IntegerProperty() 
    property_6 = ndb.StructuredProperty(A) 
    date_added = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True, indexed=False) 
    date_modified = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True, indexed=False)
```

My Query code:

```
qry_1 = B.query(B.property_5==input_value) # or B.query(B.property_6.computed_property_2==input_value) 
record_list = qry_1.fetch()
```

When I perform the above query on entity of model B, would any write operation be performed? (especially for the ComputedProperty and DateTimeProperty(with "auto_now") properties)

If yes, would it be rate limited to 1 write per second (i think that is the limit for free apps)

If yes, and if i have 50 entities matching the query, would it first complete the write operation(mentioned above) before completing the query and returning the matched entity set (any estimate of the query completion time)

Any difference in the above answers if I replace the following line in class B

```
property_6 = ndb.StructuredProperty(A)
```

with

```
property_6 = ndb.StructuredProperty(A, repeated=True)
```

Comment: Class B has no property_3 attribute. Is it a typo?

Comment: @SlawekRewaj Thanks and sorry for the typo.. I have corrected it..

Comment: The limitation to 1 write/sec applies to free and paid apps. Actually means 1 write/sec per entity group. Entity groups allow transactions or cross-transactions by sharing the same parent(s) (a.k.a. ancestors) and strongly consistent queries. This limitation can easily become a bottleneck for your app and make it to scale less. So it makes sense to model the entity groups in a way that makes it unlikely to hit this limit even if quadrillions of users work with your app. For example: Comments/Posts have the user as parent. It is unlikely that a user does more than 1 write op per second.

Answer (score 0):

There are no write operations by performing queries. The same applies to the two variations with StructuredProperty. Also `auto_now_add` and `auto_now` are only set during write operations. I'm not 100% sure, but as far as I understand the docs, computed properties are also updated at write (I haven't used them yet).

Comment: The [Computed Properties doc](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties#computed) confirms that computed properties are updated during entity writes to give the Datastore viewer a value to search for and display, and that the values are recomputed during reads (but not rewritten during reads).